# sed command failure with curly braces and double quotes values

Tags: json, sed, environment-variables, tcsh

I have a file with the following content

```
(ABC)
```

I create an env variable with the following command

```
setenv ABC  {"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}}
```

Then I run the sed command

```
sed 's|(ABC)|('"$ABC"')|' myFile
```

This returns with this

```
a:b:http://c a:d:http://e
```

It shuld actually return this

```
{"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}
```

Any ideas on what I am missing

Comment: probably shell issue... works for me on bash... `s="{'key':{'key':'value'}}"` followed by `echo '(ABC)' | sed 's/(ABC)/('"$s"')/'` gives `({'key':{'key':'value'}})`

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, I have actually updated the question with the actual values, the '/' in the http were an issue so I used pipe but now running into other issue, can you please look at the updated ques?

Comment: again, it works for me on bash... my guess is still whatever shell you are using might need something else to work

Comment: so if I add single quotes while setting the variable it works for me

Comment: hw to create an env variable with single qutes

Comment: You need to specify what shell you are using. Add a tag please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [braces and double quotes are metacharacters in C shell](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-7), you have to either escape them with backslash, like this:

```
setenv ABC \{\"a\":\{\"b\":\"http://c\",\"d\":\"http://e\"\}\}
```

or, better, **wrap the complete value in single quotes**:

```
setenv ABC '{"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}}'
```

Either way, you'll get:

```
$ echo "$ABC"
{"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}}
```

**On contrary**, if you don't escape or quote the value in `setenv` statement, like you did in the question, you'll get:

```
$ echo "$ABC"
a:b:http://c a:d:http://e
```

and that's what you were getting (`sed` had nothing to do with the problem).

Comment: Beware that in sed under csh/tcsh that you need to escape `!` even in single quotes.