# how to use sed command to enclose a variable value in single quotes

Tags: json, sed, csh, single-quotes

I set the env variable like this

```
setenv ENV {"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}}
```

I use sed like this

```
sed 's|(ENV)|('"$ENV"')|' aFile
```

It replaces `(ENV)` with the following

```
(a:b:http://c a:d:http://e)
```

However if I set the variable like this within single quotes

```
setenv ENV '{"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}}'
```

It replaces like this

```
({"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}})
```

But I would like the output of sed for `(ENV)` to be

```
('{"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's important to quote (or escape) your variable on definition (with `setenv`), as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331541/404556), since braces and double quotes (among others) are [metacharacters in C shell](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-7).

You can **quote the complete value with single quotes**:

```
$ setenv ABC '{"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}}'
$ echo "$ABC"
{"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}}
```

Or, **escape metacharacters with backslashes**, like this:

```
$ setenv ABC \{\"a\":\{\"b\":\"http://c\",\"d\":\"http://e\"\}\}
$ echo "$ABC"
{"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}}
```

Now, for the **`sed` part** of your question -- and how to quote the variable on replacement.

Just add single quotes in your `sed` replacement expression and you're done:

```
$ setenv ABC '{"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}}'
$ echo '(ABC)' | sed 's|(ABC)|('"'$ABC'"')|'
('{"a":{"b":"http://c","d":"http://e"}}')
```

Note, in addition, you should also take care of **escaping `sed` replacement metacharacters** (these three only: `\`, `/`, and `&`) in your variable. You seem aware of this, since you already use `|` as a delimiter in you regex, but if you are unsure of what your variable contains, it's always good to escape it. For details on reliable escaping metacharacters in `sed`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/404556). In short, to escape a single-line replacement pattern, run it through `sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g'`.

Comment: Thanks but after the evaluation the value is returned only as a string between the single quotes. I want the exact same value to be evaluated. Along with the single quotes.

Comment: Thank you but I should have been clearer, I cannot change the way I se the variable, but Can I use sed to add back the quotes while evaluatiing?

Comment: .. and **please read** [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It seems you're not a new user on SO, and yet seem to accept only your own answers, and upvote none of the others. That's not a nice way to behave on SO.

Comment: sure thanks, I generally try out the answer and accept if it works.  Its also not nice to assume that I verified your answer and it worked for me

Comment: Hey, seems to work thanks. For the answer and the downvote lol

Comment: Ok, great. I've clarified your question a little bit and removed the dv. I've also updated my answer to better answer you question after all additional info from comments. I feel I answered the first part of your question in the answer to your previous question, though.. Btw, upvoting and accepting answers is a small thing you can do that goes a long way to help and thank the community for helping you. I haven't meant anything bad in my previous comment, but please make it a habit to upvote and accept. Thanks.